# How can I deploy a Next JS and Pocketbase project to any server?

Tags: next.js, vercel, fly, pocketbase

I have a Next JS project with Pocketbase as its backend. The project runs well on localhost but when I upload to a server, one of two things goes wrong. Either:

1. The Next JS works but Pocketbase doesn't (on Vercel), or
2. The frontend doesn't work so I can't tell whether the Pocketbase is working anyway.( on Fly.io)

P.S. Here are my docker and fly.toml files:

1. Docker:

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
#RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    unzip \
    ca-certificates

RUN npm install

COPY . .

# RUN yarn build

RUN npm run dev

#RUN pocketbase serve

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["/pocketbase", "serve"]
```

2. fly.toml:

```
# fly.toml file generated for ebesa on 2023-04-05T20:15:31+03:00

app = "ebesa"
kill_signal = "SIGINT"
kill_timeout = 5
primary_region = "lax"

[experimental]
  auto_rollback = true

[build]
  [build.args]
    PB_VERSION = "0.7.7"

[env]
  PORT = "3000"

[mounts]
  source = "pb_data"
  destination = "/pb_data"

[[services]]
  protocol = "tcp"
  internal_port = 3000
  processes = ["app"]

  [[services.ports]]
    port = 80
    handlers = ["http"]
    force_https = true

  [[services.ports]]
    port = 443
    handlers = ["tls", "http"]
  [services.concurrency]
    type = "connections"
    hard_limit = 25
    soft_limit = 20

  [[services.tcp_checks]]
    interval = "15s"
    timeout = "2s"
    grace_period = "1s"
    restart_limit = 0
```

I tried integrating docker and editing the fly.toml file before uploading the project to fly.io, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to host pocketbase somewhere like a VPS. Vercel is hosting your Next.js app, nothing more nothing less.